# VB 6 listbox adding same data

Tags: combobox, vb6, listbox

i have a problem, I'm currently making my project, my problem is i cant make my same order be on the same line if i ordered it at different time. for example i ordered 1 burger with cheese, then i ordered it again, what i want to happen in my list is that they'll just add the quantity i ordered instead of writing it down again. i have no idea what codes should i write, i tried different codes but it doesn't work so i deleted it. excuse my English. thank you.

[These is what i want to avoid.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fJj4.png)

Comment: The one will help me, you just saved my subject! :)

Answer (score 0):

you didn't post any code!!!

```
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateProduct(sProduct As String, ByVal Qty As Long, ByVal Amnt As Currency)
Dim i As Long
i = GetStringIndex(List1, sProduct)

If (i = -1) Then ' there is no match?
  List1.AddItem sProduct
  List2.AddItem Str(Qty)
  List3.AddItem Str(Amnt)
Else
  List2.List(i) = Val(List2.List(i)) + Qty
  List3.List(i) = Val(List3.List(i)) + Amnt
End If
End Sub
Function GetStringIndex(lst As ListBox, ByVal sItem As String) As Long
    For GetStringIndex = 0 To lst.ListCount - 1
        If lst.List(GetStringIndex) = sItem Then Exit Function
    Next
    GetStringIndex = -1
End Function
```

Comment: thank you but 'GetStringIndex' does not work it says compile error: sub or function not defined. can you help me again pls? :)

Comment: it was supposed that you implement it by yourself, but anyway, here is the full working code.